# Creating users under specific tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle19c

I am supposed to create two users for the Customer Service department and one user for the Inventory department.

Below is the code for one of the users I was creating for customer service department but I don't know how to place the user under the Customer Service department. The Customer Service Department is a table that is already in the database

```
CREATE USER Patricia
IDENTIFIED BY Patricia001
DEFAULT TABLESPACE extra_tbs
DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE Temp
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON extra_tbs
PROFILE Secretary 
PASSWORD EXPIRE
GRANT CREATE SESSION
ACCOUNT UNLOCK
LIMIT 
FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS 3 
PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME 1
PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 60
IDLE_TIME 10;
```

Comment: Break that down to one specific problem per question posted. And maybe https://dba.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for these questions. (Don't forget to delete the one here should you decide to post over there.)

Comment: You don't create users under tables.  you can grant rights to a user for a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong here:

First, as mentioned above, users are not created in tables. Privileges on tables, like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` are granted to users.

Second, your syntax for `CREATE USER` is incorrect on several counts:

a) Of the various "options" you have included, the actual `CREATE USER`
command should *only* include the following:

```
CREATE USER Patricia
IDENTIFIED BY Patricia001
DEFAULT TABLESPACE extra_tbs
DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE Temp
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON extra_tbs
PROFILE Secretary 
PASSWORD EXPIRE
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

b) Granting a privilege like `CREATE SESSION` is a separate command:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO PATRICIA;
```

c) And the `LIMIT` clause is part of a profile, not a user. You have already referenced the `SECRETARY` profile, so presumably these settings are already covered there.

See `CREATE USER` documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html#GUID-F0246961-558F-480B-AC0F-14B50134621C